# map multi states to a component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to map two parts of the state to my component. Is the way below ok to map multi states to a component? it works but I don't know if it makes you experts laugh at my code !! I mean is there another way that you rather?

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return  ( state.auth, state.sina );
};
```

this one also worked:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return  {...state.auth, ...state.sina};
};
```

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = ({ auth, sina }) => ({ auth, sina })`

Comment: @madox2  yours worked, but then i tried this `const mapStateToProps = state => ({ state.auth, state.sina });`  which is the same as yours but it throws errors, why? they are the same aren't they?

Comment: don't let confuse yourself with this fancy syntax. it is combination of object destructuring and property shorthands. for the beginning simply use object literals :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` is regular javascript function. You can return object literal with any properties you wish, for example:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return  {
    auth: state.auth,
    sina: state.sina
  };
};
```

And then access it inside of your component:

```
this.props.auth;
this.props.sina;
```

Comment: thanks i worked, but why this doesn't work `const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return  {
    state.auth,
    state.sina
  };
};`

Comment: to create object literal you need to define keys and values. what you are trying to do is not valid javascript